# Merging two nested lists based on the index in Python

Tags: python, list

Hello my question has two parts.

**First part**  : how to merge two nested lists based on the index , for example :

```
L1 = [[1,2],[4,5]]
L2 = [[11,22],[44,55]]
```

I want to merge the above nested lists based on their index so that i get an output like :

```
L3 = [ [[1,11],[2,22]] , [[4,44],[5,55]] ]
```

The **second part** of the problem is to add a constant value to all the nested lists so that the output is :

```
L3 = [ [[1,11,0],[2,22,0]] , [[4,44,0],[5,55,0]] ]
```

Comment: You say "based on their index", but really you mean "based on the number contained in their name". It generally an extremely bad idea to base decisions and logic in your code on the names of your variables. After all, users of your program (both those that would import functions from it and end users) have no concept of your code. You should consider what problem you're actually trying solve...

Comment: `numpy` would make this easier.  Do you intend to use it?

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm a fan of `numpy`, but this problem is so trivial that throwing a heavy package like `numpy` at it would be serious overkill. All that's needed is a simple list comprehension.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that you are expected to make some attempt to solve the problem yourself first, and that you are only supposed to ask one question at a time. The two parts of your problem are clearly not related to each other and can be tackled independently, so they are separate questions.

Comment: Start by trying to solve a simpler problem. Given single items from `L1` and `L2`, like `[1,2]` and `[11,22]`, can you produce the corresponding element for `L3`, i.e. `[[1,11],[2,22]]`? Can you think of other names for this operation, or ways of conceptualizing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension with `zip` for both requirements:

```
>>> [[list(x) for x in zip(*t)] for t in zip(L1, L2)]
[[[1, 11], [2, 22]], [[4, 44], [5, 55]]]
```

and

```
>>> [[[a, b, 0] for a, b in zip(*t)] for t in zip(L1, L2)]
[[[1, 11, 0], [2, 22, 0]], [[4, 44, 0], [5, 55, 0]]]
```